# Finding $n$-th root of $p_1$ modulo $p_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, congruences, legendre-symbol, jacobi-symbol

How to calculate $n$-th root of a prime number $p_1\ \mbox{modulo}\ p_2$? 
That is: $x = p_1^\frac{1}{n}\ \bmod \ p_2$.
I have a notion that somehow Legendre symbols can be use, however I can't quite grasp the concept.

Comment: Legendre symbols are great if $n=2$. They would also be helpful if $n$ is a power of $2$, beyond that, not so much.

Comment: You probably want to think of this in terms of solving the polynomial congruence $x^n-p_1\equiv 0\pmod{p_2}$.

Comment: Apparently no way other than brute force. For example $x^3\equiv p \pmod q$ has no solution for $p=2,3,5$ and $q=7$ but how can you act if $p$ and $q$ are big?

Comment: This seems to be a really hard problem in general, even if we are just asking about the existence of a solution and not how to calculate it. I know of some special cases like $p_1=2$ $n=3$, but that case requires cubic reciprocity to answer for which $p_2$ there exists a solution and it's not a particularly simple answer.

Comment: I found something that can be useful:http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/179

Answer (score 1):

To ease the notations, write $p=p_2$ and $l=p_1$. The problem is to solve the congruence $x^n\equiv l\pmod p$. The map "raising to the $n$-th power" in $\mathbf F_p^*$ has kernel $\mu_n (\mathbf F_p)$ (= the group of $n$-th roots of $1$ contained in $\mathbf F_p^*$) and cokernel $\mathbf F_p^*/{\mathbf F_p^*}^n$. This can be conveniently summarized by the exact sequence $1 \to \mu_n (\mathbf F_p)\to\mathbf F_p^* \to \mathbf F_p^* \to \mathbf F_p^*/{\mathbf F_p^*}^n \to 1$ which shows, since we are dealing with finite cyclic groups, that  $\mu_n (\mathbf F_p)$ and $\mathbf F_p^*/{\mathbf F_p^*}^n$ have the same order = *gcd* ($n, p-1$). Let us consider two extreme cases, then the general case : (i) if $n$ and $p-1$ are coprime, then $\mathbf F_p^*={\mathbf F_p^*}^n$, which means that for any integer $a$ not divisible by $p$, the congruence  $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$ has one and only one solution ;  (ii) if $n$ divides $p-1$, the previous congruence has a solution iff $a^{\frac {p-1}n }\equiv 1\pmod p$, and in this case, there are exactly $n$ solutions which differ (multiplicatively) by an $n$-th root of $1$ ; (iii) in the general case, denoting by $[a]$ the class of $a\pmod p$, the solvability of the congruence $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$ is equivalent to $[a]\in {\mathbf F_p^*}^n$. Again, since we are dealing with finite cyclic groups, this simply means that the order of $[a]\in {\mathbf F_p^*}$ divides the order of the subgroup group ${\mathbf F_p^*}^n$, which is $(p-1)/gcd (p-1, n)$. Note that we don't need to take $a=l$.

As you suspected, the main interest of this problem lies in the so called *power residue symbol* which generalizes the quadratic and cubic residue symbols (Gauss, Eisenstein) using class field theory (for CFT over number fields, see e.g. Cassels-Fröhlich, chap.VII by Tate). Let me try to give just an idea, sticking to the base field $K=\mathbf Q(\mu_n)$. For $p$ not dividing $a$ as above, suppose further that $p$ is unramified in $K$, i.e. $p$ does not divide $disc(K)$. Then, for any prime ideal $P$ of $K$ above $p$, $n$ divides $NP-1$ (where $NP$ is the norm of $P$). Moreover (and more deeply), given  $L=K(\sqrt [n] a)$ with $a\in K^*$ and not divisible by $P$, one can construct the so called *Frobenius map* $F_{L/K}(P)$ (op. cit., §3) and define the symbol $(\frac aP)\in \mu_n$ by the equation $F_{L/K}(P)(\sqrt [n] a)/(\sqrt [n] a) = (\frac aP)$. In our particular case, $(\frac aP)$ is the unique $n$-th root of $1$ such that $(\frac aP)\equiv a^{\frac {NP-1}n}\pmod P$ (generalized *Euler criterion*). The name "power residue symbol" comes from the following property : $(\frac aP) =1$ iff the congruence $x^n\equiv a\pmod P$ has a solution $x$ in the ring of integers of $K_P$ (= the completion of $K$ at $P$). References : op. cit., exercises 1.4, 1.5, 1.9,2.14 .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a faster way to solve this problem other than checking all the numbers from $ 0 $ to $ p_2-1 $. In fact a lot of the time there is no solution.

If you want to check if there is a solution without actually finding it use this method:

If $n$ doesn't divide $p_2-1$ then there is a solution.
If $n$ does divide $p_2-1$, then there is a solution iff $${p_1}^{\frac{p_2-1}{n}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p_2} $$

This may not seem much simpler but it is faster for a computer to do, especially if you are dealing with big numbers.